# How to retrieve all AWS permissions associated with the following role

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to retrieve all AWS permissions associated with the following role?

```
customer_app_role
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetRegistryPolicy",
        "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
        "ecr:DescribePullThroughCacheRules",
        "ecr:DescribeImageReplicationStatus",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:BatchGetRepositoryScanningConfiguration",
        "ecr:GetRegistryScanningConfiguration",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetRepository",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all AWS permissions associated with the following role"? Isn't that what you are showing us?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to fetch in programmatic fashion

Comment: DId you tried something to achieve in `programamtic fashion`?

Answer (score 1):

May the bash be with you:

```bash
ROLE_NAME=some_example_role

for policy_arn in $(aws --output text iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name "${ROLE_NAME}" --query 'AttachedPolicies[*].PolicyArn')
do
  echo "-------------- ${policy_arn} --------------"
  version=$(aws iam --output text list-policy-versions --policy-arn "${policy_arn}" --query 'Versions[?IsDefaultVersion==`true`].VersionId')
  aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "${policy_arn}" --version-id "${version}" --query 'PolicyVersion.Document.Statement' | grep -v '>DUMMY<'
done
```

```json
-------------- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/Policy1 --------------
[
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:GetParameter"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/AmazonCloudWatch-*"
    }
]
-------------- arn:aws:iam::12345678:policy/policy2 --------------
[
    {
        "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Sid": ""
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
        "Sid": ""
    }
]
```

＊About `grep -v '>DUMMY<'` → aws cli print large json using pagination (you have to press Enter or Space to see end of output). I using dummy `grep` to prevent it (whole output will be printed)